# In the Critical Section Issue ,should processes in exit section influence the decision that which process will execute its critical section next?

Tags: operating-system, critical-section

[image]

The book is Operating System Concepts by Avi Silberschatz . Since processes in exit section have already executed their critical section , should they be allowed to influence the decision ?

Comment: In the title you ask if they *can,* but in the actual question if they *should* be able to. I can't think of a scenario where I would answer *yes* to either question, but it's not really clear what the scope of your question is. Can you clarify why you want to know this, and how you would rationalize a design where this is possible? Not sure this is properly on-topic for Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: The book says any process not in required section can influence the decision making part , but I want to know if that is actually the case since it looks wrong

Comment: Huh? The text you are quoting says something quite different: *"…..only those processes that are not executing in their remainder section"*

Comment: That is what I want to clarify .... if a process is in remainder section that means it is done with its critical section and if in exit section also it means the same thing .... but we are allowing processes in exit state ( as per the text ) to influence the decision making . So how is it different from allowing processes in remainder state to influence the decisions ( if you are allowing in exit state you should also allow in remainder or you should not allow in both remainder and exit )

Comment: Defining the generic language used in these operating system texts is a lot like trying to nail jelly to the wall.  The "exit section" needs to restore whatever plumbing is used so the OS is ready to allow another process to enter a critical section.  On modern machines that is a single cpu instruction, albeit wrapped in a kernel call.  It is fairly implicit that while this cleanup is happening, it is not yet ready to allow another process to enter.  And no, while a process is in the "remainder section" then it is executing the code that is protected by the critical section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that the intent is to say *only processes which are competing to get to execute their critical section are allowed to be involved in deciding which one of them actually gets this permission.*

My reading of this is that the code is partitioned into four non-overlapping categories; the three sections *entry*, *critical,* and *exit* together relate to the critical-section problem, and the entirety of the rest of the program is the *remainder.* The text specifically says that code in the remainder section cannot participate in deciding which process is granted exclusive access to the critical region.

I *suppose* the author doesn't want to rule out the possibility that a process in the exit section could get to decide *"process Y, you go next"* though the usual solution is different (Dijkstra's semaphore algorithm).